# Не могу запустить прогграмму без отладки в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

я хотел изучить язык C#? купил книгу Герберта Шилдта полное руководство C# 4.0.
первая программа в этой книге выглядет так

```
using System;
class Example
{
    Static Void Main()
    {
        Console.Writeline("HELLO WORLD!!!");
    }
}
```

я переписал эту программу в визуал студио смотрю в книге как запустить программу в этом приложение, делаю всё по инструкции, и тут первая проблемма. В книге сказанно "4. Выберите команду создать элемент чтобы открыть диологовое окно ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ НОВОГО ЭЛЕМЕНТА. выберите сначала элемент КОД из списка УСТАНОВЛЕННЫЕ ШАБЛОНЫ, а затем шаблон ФАИЛ С ТЕКСТОМ ПРОГРАММЫ и измените имя файла на Example.cs" тк у меня нет ни элемента КОД, ни списка УСТАНОВЛЕННЫЕ ШАБЛОНЫ, ни ФАИЛ С ТЕКСТОМ ПРОГРАММЫ.
Ладно я подумал что из-за того что у меня более новая веррсия здесь это не нужно, попробывал использовать КЛАСС VISUL C# и ТЕКСТОВЫЙ ФАИЛ, но не чего не помогало, далее в книге написанно "7. скомпилируйте программу, выбрав команду построение => построить решение" "8. выполните программу выбрав ЗАПУСК БЕЗ ОТЛАДКИ" так вот вторая проблемма: у меня затемнена команда ЗАПУСК БЕЗ ОТЛАДКИ, и я не чего не могу сделать (код переписан точь в точь кроме надписи) и так пришло время третей проблемы: помимо всего этого список ошибок говорит мне что "требуется ";"", но в программе с книги её нет и если я её ставлю то выходит сообщение "недопустиый токен ";"".
К слову в книге указанно как можно запустить программу через текстовый редактор, (Я использую PS Pad) четвёртая проблема: я немогу скомпилировать код.
в книге указанно: 
1. Введитеисходный текст программы, используя текстовый редактор.
2. Скомпилируйте программу с помошью компилятора csc.exe.(что это?)
3. выполните программу.
и так что я делал?
После записи кода в пспад я пытался откомпилировать код в редакторе, изменить расширение на cs. csc.exe. csc. exe.
Нечего не работает, пожалуйста обьясните что я делаю не так? ПОЖАЛУЙСТА!!!

Comment: Создайте в Visual Studio консольное приложение (.Net Framework). Появится готовый шаблон.

Comment: @FredPerry
а как это сделать? Я первый раз в целом в жизни запустил визуал студио)

Comment: Студия 2019? Запускаете, выбираете создание проекта. Находите консольное приложение (.Net Framework) и нажимаете кнопку "Создать".

Comment: @FredPerry

Там получается в тип проекта "консоль"?
у меня только здесь есть хоть чтото связанное с консолью.

Comment: Все верно, тип проекта - консоль. Еще есть поиск, в нем можете начать писать слово "консольное" и вам выдаст список доступных вариантов

Comment: @FredPerry

А дальше как? Я упоминал что у меня нет элементов указанных в книге. Простите что мучаю, очень хочу в этом разобратся.

Comment: Проект с шаблоном создали?

Comment: @FredPerry
да насколько я понимаю.

Comment: Тогда внутри метода Main пишите Console.Writeline("Hello"); а на следующей строке Console.ReadLine(); Потом нажимаете f5.

Comment: @FredPerry
using System;
class Example {

    Static Void Main() {
    Console.Writeline ("HELLO WORLD!!!");
    Console.Readline ();
    }
}
так?

Comment: Вероятно, есть смысл взять более новую книгу, в которой будут описаны новые версии C# и Visual Studio.